# Append initialized list

Tags: prolog

If I have a pre-initialized list, for example:

```
List = [_1663, _1665, _1667]
```

How can I put a variable (like a simple integer) in this list, taking up the first free spot?

I tried:

```
append(5, List).
```

But that doesn't work.
The list must be pre-initialized like above. Any ideas? 
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to instantiate the first element of the list, you can do it like so: `?- List = [5,_,_].` Prolog will then answer something like this: `List = [5, _G204, _G207].`

Comment: @tas Is it possible to have the integer to automatically go to the first free element in the list? For example if the list is already [1,2,3,_1564,_1179] so it goes in the 4th position? The pre-initialized list can be of variable length unfortunately.

Comment: That is possible using a recursive predicate that tests list entries with the `var/1` predicate. But if you are a Prolog beginner, it is almost certainly not what you want to learn first. You could update the question with more information on what you *really* want to do.

Comment: @lurker I edited the question, thanks for the headsup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog will not automatically instantiate the next free variable in a list. You can easily, though, do this with a predicate:

```
bind_first_free_element(Element, List) :-
    once(bind_free_element(Element, List)).

bind_free_element(X, [Y|_]) :-
    var(Y), X = Y.
bind_free_element(X, [_|T]) :-
    bind_free_element(X, T).
```

When you query, you get:

```
2 ?- L = [a,X,Y,b,Z], bind_free_element(5, L).
L = [a, 5, Y, b, Z],
X = 5 ;
L = [a, X, 5, b, Z],
Y = 5 ;
L = [a, X, Y, b, 5],
Z = 5 ;
false.
```

So you can see that `bind_free_element` shows *all* of the possible solutions for binding a free element. Thus, we use `bind_first_free_element/2` that uses `once/1` to only seek the first solution:

```
3 ?- L = [a,X,Y,b,Z], bind_first_free_element(5, L).
L = [a, 5, Y, b, Z],
X = 5.
```

Comment: The first solution for `?- L = [a, X, Y, b, Z], bind_free_element(a, L).` does not bind `X` (or any other variable in the list).

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie my apologies, I misunderstood your comment at first and have updated my answer accordingly.